# Instance not callable 'tuple' object

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Need to call a `capture()` method (omitted) in the `Camera` class. Just running the code in a script runs it OK:

```
# import io, picamera, etc..
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution(self.camwidth, self.camheight)
    camera.start_preview()
```

When I try to make it object oriented it fails:

```
class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, cam_width, cam_height):
        self.camwidth = cam_width
        self.camheight = cam_height
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
            camera.resolution(self.camwidth, self.camheight)
            camera.start_preview()
            time.sleep(2)

camera = Camera(32, 24)
```

The error looks like this:

```
File "ActionScript.py", line 23, in <module> camera = Camera(32, 24)
File "ActionScript.py", line 13, in __init__ camera.resolution(self.camwidth,self.camheight)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I have tried different ways around this, but the line:

```
camera.resolution(self.camwidth, self.camheight)
```

.. seems to the one it has a problem with from inside an object. Always "tuple object is not callable. I have also tried setting `__init__()` to just registering the 32x24 values and a `cameraSetup()` method to run the setup with the same result after calling `camera.cameraSetup()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

camera.resolution is a tuple. This means its a array data structure which cannot be modified past its instantiation. You definitely can't call it like a function either. Instead, point it to a new tuple.

```
camera.resolution = (self.camwidth, self.camheight)
```

source: http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes1.html